# Simple Recursive Function - taking a string and returning it n amount of times

Tags: racket

Write a recursive function (string* str n) that takes two arguments: a string x and a non-negative integer n. The non-negative integers are defined inductively as:
number ::= 0
| number + 1
string* returns a string consisting of n occurrences of str. For example:

```
> (string* "Eugene" 3)
     "EugeneEugeneEugene"
```

You will want to use Racket's string-append function. Remember that the base case when recurring on a non-negative integer is 0.

So far I have tried:

```
(define string*
  (lambda (x n)
    (if (null? x)
        '""
        (if (zero? n)
            (string* (string-append x x)
                     (sub1 n))))))
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to end the recursion and print the final string.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Null?](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=null%3F#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._null%7E3f%29%29) returns #true for empty list. You don't work with lists here, so you don't need it.
2. Base case is `n = 0`, which returns `""` (empty string). Predicate for that is [zero?](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/number-types.html?q=zero%3F#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._zero%7E3f%29%29) or `(= n 0)`.
3. In other cases, you will append together string and result of recursive call.

```
(define string*
  (lambda (str n)
    (if (zero? n) ""
        (string-append str
                       (string* str (sub1 n))))))
```

`> (string* "Eugene" 3)` -> `"EugeneEugeneEugene"`